# How to plot Time Series graph in Python for both odd & even years?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science

I plotted a time series graph in Python but it is displaying only even years in graph. I want both even & odd years to be displayed. Can anyone suggest. Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(data['Year'],data['Sale ($)'])
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Sale ($)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matplotlib`dataformatters`set_major_locator()`and`set_major_formatter()` to force matplotlib to show the dates and format you want to see. Below is an example of the same with some random data. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Create random data
sales = {'Sale ($)':np.random.randint(30, size=(20))}
data = pd.DataFrame(sales)
data['Year'] = pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-01', end = '2023-01-01', periods = len(data))

## Your code
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(data['Year'],data['Sale ($)'])
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Sale ($)')

## Add below lines...
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())   #to get a tick every 1 year
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))     #Show Year format

plt.show()
```

[image]